# Install Acellera's HTMD using Conda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

Following [the installation documentation](https://software.acellera.com/install-htmd.html), I'm trying to use Conda to install the `htmd` program from the Acellera suite on my Mac but this error is shown:

```bash
(base) MacBook-Pro-di-Eleonora:~ eleonora$ conda install -c acellera
-c conda-forge htmd 

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. 
Retrying with flexible solve. 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. 
Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - htmd

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/acellera/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/acellera/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

The package appears to be available on [their Anaconda Cloud channel](https://anaconda.org/acellera). Why is it not being found, and how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

The Conda package is only built for the **linux-64** platform. It cannot be installed directly on Mac OS X.

Alternatively, you might look into running it through a Docker container, starting from something like [a Miniforge3 container](https://hub.docker.com/r/condaforge/miniforge3).